# uart-baudrate is changed multiple times during boot

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, boot

I can not figure out, where the uart, baudrate is changed in the linux kernel.

I am using the adi_uart4.c driver (not in the major 4.14 kernel yet). But it is designed like all the other in driver/tty/serial/

While booting:

1. CONFIG_BAUDRATE 115200              -> uboot baudrate
2. earlyprintk=serial,uart0,115200     -> cmdline arg in uboot
3. console=ttySC0,115200               -> cmdline arg in uboot
4. ??? -> set to 56700

Linux boot output stops, because of baudrate change:

```
[..]
Freeing unused kernel memory: 1024K                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Starting logging: OK                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Starting mdev...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Starting watchdog...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Initializing random number generator... done.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Starting network...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
/bin/sh: run-parts: not found                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Starting inetd: OK                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
��怘�~3f<��<����f<���3�f��Æ�����`?怘���<f?����`<?����`?<��~<�����������
```

Comment: *"Linux boot stops at:..."* -- Don't you mean the console output stops?  How do you know that the kernel has actually *"stopped"*?   Since userland has started, the likeliest program to change the baudrate would be a `getty`, e.g. inspect **/etc/inittab**.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @sawdust.

There was an additional userspace change in `/etc/inittab`

```
# Put a getty on the serial port                                
ttySC0::respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttySC0 56700 vt100 # GENERIC_SERIAL
```